# Node.js Process finished with exit code 255

Tags: node.js, angular

I’m trying to build my angular project, but at my ng build, after a few moments he tells me
Process finished with exit code 255, I attach the terminal message, and I can’t understand the reason, I tried to re-install node.js and npm and also tried to re-import the modules on intelliJ , but the problem persists
Somebody had a similar problem and can help me?

this is the  message :

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" run build

> skote-angular-vertical@2.1.100 prebuild
> echo ECHO npm_package_version: %npm_package_version% && FOR /f "tokens=*" %a in ('npm version patch --git-tag-version -m "Upgrade to %s before prod build"') do echo ECHO -- && SET OUTPUT=%a && call echo ECHO new version: %OUTPUT% && echo ECHO 
npm_package_version: %npm_package_version% && echo ECHO git add package.json package-lock.json && git add package.json package-lock.json && echo ECHO git commit -m "Bump version" && REM call git commit -m "Bump version" && echo ECHO call git tag
 %OUTPUT% && call git tag %OUTPUT% && echo ECHO PREBUILD END

s not expected.

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: What is `skote-angular-vertical`?

Comment: Skote is the template I use in the application

Comment: I solved the issue, installing nvm and doing, I found the correct version.